# no respone .chzn-select two dropdown with ajax and codeigniter

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, codeigniter

Need help to every body why wrong with my code i want to make a two dropdown,. one drop down to master data and second dropdown to child from data master.. if i cannot make .chzn-select  from jquery it's never mind but if action edit the child data the respone is wrong,. and then i make .chzn-select but nothing respone, this is my code :

/My view
//the jquery.min.js and  chosen.jquery.js and chosen.css  has been loaded

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 $(".chzn-select").chosen().change(function(){

    alert('here');
    $("#rack > option").remove();  
    var id_lantai = $("#id_lantai").val(); 
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>power/get_rack_perlantai"+id_lantai, 
        success: function(rack){
            $.each(rack,function(id_rack,nama_rack){ 
                var opt = $('<option />');   
                        opt.val(id_rack);
                        opt.text(nama_rack);
                $('#rack').append(opt);
            });
        }
    })
}); 
</script>  
<tr><td>FLOOR *</td><td>:</td>
           <td>                  
                <select data-placeholder="Floor" class="chzn-select" style="width:200px;" tabindex="2" id="id_lantai" class="required" name="id_lantai" >
                <option value="" val_nm_prd="">-SELECT FLOOR -</option>
                <?php 
                foreach($id_lantai as $u){
                if($u['id_lantai']==$val){
                $selected="selected";
                }else{
                $selected="";
                }
            ?>
            <option value="<?=$u['id_lantai']?>" <?=$selected?> ><?=$u['lantai']?></option>
            <?php } ?>
            </select>
        </td> 
    </tr>  

    <tr><td>RACK *</td><td>:</td>
       <td>                  
            <select data-placeholder="Rack" class="chzn-select" style="width:200px;" tabindex="2" id="id_rack" class="required" name="id_rack" >
            <option value="" val_nm_prd="">-SELECT RACK -</option>
            <?php 

                foreach($id_rack as $u){
                if($u['id_lantai']==$vall()){
                $selected="selected";
                }else{
                $selected="";
                }
            ?>
            <option value="<?=$u['id_rack']?>" <?=$selected?> ><?=$u['nama_rack']?></option>
            <?php } ?>
            </select>
        </td> 
    </tr>
```

//MY CONTROLLERS

```
function get_rack_perlantai($idlantai)
{    
     header('Content-Type: application/x-json; charset=utf-8');

     echo(json_encode($this->power_model->get_rack($idlantai)));

}
```

//MY MODELS

```
    function get_lantai() {

    $this->db->select('id_lantai, lantai');

    $query = $this->db->get('xl_lantai_server');

    $lantaivariabel = array();

    if ($query -> result()) {

     foreach ($query->result() as $lantaix) {

     $lantaivariabel[$lantaix -> id_lantai] = $lantaix -> lantai;

     } 
        return $lantaivariabel;

     }

     else 
     {

        return FALSE;

     }

} 

//Query untuk ajak lantai & rack


    function get_rack($idlantai = null)
    {

         $this->db->select('id_rack, nama_rack');

         if($idlantai != NULL){

         $this->db->where('id_lantai', $idlantai);

         }

         $query = $this->db->get('xl_rack');

         $xl_rack = array();

         if($query->result()){

         foreach ($query->result() as $rack) {

         $xl_rack[$rack->id_rack] = $rack->nama_rack;

            }

         return $xl_rack;

         }
         else

            {

         return FALSE;

            }

    }
```

sorry my english not good,.:)

Comment: I highly recommend you to indentate and format your code properly.

Answer (score 0):

1st problem is in your ajax call check url it should be like the following, then you can get the passed value in your controller and also no need of type:"POST" in your ajax call as your are not sending any data.

```
url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>power/get_rack_perlantai/"+id_lantai,
```

consider the last slash "/" before appending the variable.